# Apt upgrade on WSL is super slow / unusable

Tags: performance, download, windows-subsystem-for-linux, updates, apt

I was trying to setup a build environment on WSL. After starting it up and running `sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y` It started doing its thing. But then got super slow (20kb/s) So i deleted the whole WSL and redownloaded it... Same issue. I tried disabling IPV6 in my sysctl that also didnt work.

[image: slow speed]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the local closet mirror for you [from here](https://%20https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) and update `sources.list` file

`sudo sed -i "s/archive.ubuntu.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/" /etc/apt/sources.list`

Found this at [source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2477#issuecomment-371285353)

Comment: Sadly this didnt work, still super slow UPDATE: After restartibng my PC and restarting WSL it worked

Answer (score 3):

"It started doing its thing. But then got super slow (20kb/s) "

I had exact same problem while doing scp within linux with WSL.

You can improve network performance of WSL using Powershell as Administrator:

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-NetAdapterLso -Name vEthernet* -IncludeHidden -IPv4
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-NetAdapterLso -Name vEthernet* -IncludeHidden -IPv6                                           PS
```

**References**
[1]: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4901
[2]: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8171
[3]: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/low-internet-speed-in-wsl-2/21524829-18be-4611-bb5f-cabccd2cae31
[4]: https://townsyio.medium.com/wsl2-how-to-fix-download-speed-3edb0c348e29

Comment: I posted a similar answer in different questions that seems caused by network slowness in WSL context. Serving files, running package managers, docker pull/push, or any network-related process can be affected by this issue.